# Select file to upload using Internet Explorer in python

Tags: python, internet-explorer

I am having trouble testing an application I'm developing the site only works with IE so I had to use the "win32com.client Dispatch", but I can not interact with an input field of type file, I can not change the value for the file you want and upload.
I'm trying to do the following:

ie.Document.forms [0] .elements ["encanexo1"]. value = "file"

But the field does not change.